# How to compile DOM added by third party libraries in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using sidr( http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ ) with angular for my navigation bar. What sidr does is it copies my nav-bar's markup and puts it just before the body wrapped in its custom div.

Now I have defined a directive on my nav-bar which looks some what like this `<ul filter>....</ul>`. Since sidr is replicating my navigation bar markup I have 2 ul's with filter directive. But my directive's link function is called only once because angular dose not know about another occurrence of that directive.

My markup looks like this

```
            <ul class="side-nav nested-nav" filter>
                <li class="has-sub-menu" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
                    <a href="#" ng-bind="filter.label"></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" options>
                        <li ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
                            <a href="#" ng-bind="option.label"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

and I my directive

```
angular.module('test')
    .directive('filter', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                console.log('hello world!'):
            }
        }
    })
```

So how do I tell angular to compile the second `<ul filter>....</ul>` which was added by sidr and when ?

Comment: Would be helpful to see your code.  I did something similar to this for an overlay directive in my project using a Boostrap modal.  I manually moved the elements in the post link function of the directive so they were already compiled.  Can you put-off the copying until the post link function so the compiling is done?

Comment: I have added my code see whether that helps. Sidr is duplicating my `nested-nav` so there are 2 DOM occurrence of it but it logs only once  since angualr does not know about the 2nd occurrence created by sidr

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this jQuery plugin yet. But looking at the doc, it has this callback feature:

```
    $('#callback-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr-callback',
      source: function(name) {
        return '<h1>' + name + ' menu</h1><p>Yes! You can use a callback too ;)</p>';
      }
    });
```

So I guess you can put in your own html template into the source callback and `$compile` it.